# Can't import 'datasets' with scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I just installed Python (tried both 3.5.2 and 2.7.12 with the exact same result). I've tried Googling it and looking through issues but can't find anything on it.

The code I'm trying to run is simply the beginning of the basic tutorial:

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
digits = datasets.load_digits()
```

The error is `ImportError: cannot import name 'datasets'`.

I've tried re-installing everything. Same result over and over again. I'm on a Macbook with El Capitan which is newly installed as well.

I installed Python with pyenv, and scipy and numpy through pip. I've also upgraded pip, by the way, to the latest version.

```
import _frozen_importlib # frozen
import _imp # builtin
import sys # builtin
import '_warnings' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_thread' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_frozen_importlib_external' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
import '_io' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'marshal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'posix' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import _thread # previously loaded ('_thread')
import '_thread' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import _weakref # previously loaded ('_weakref')
import '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# installing zipimport hook
import 'zipimport' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# installed zipimport hook
# /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/encodings/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-35.pyc matches /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/encodings/__init__.py
# code object from '/Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/encodings/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-35.pyc'
# /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/codecs.cpython-35.pyc matches /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/codecs.py
# code object from '/Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/codecs.cpython-35.pyc'
import '_codecs' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'codecs' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x108ac7390>
# /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/encodings/__pycache__/aliases.cpython-35.pyc matches /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/encodings/aliases.py
# code object from '/Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/encodings/__pycache__/aliases.cpython-35.pyc'
import 'encodings.aliases' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x108af7f60>
import 'encodings' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x108ac0f60>
# /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/encodings/__pycache__/utf_8.cpython-35.pyc matches /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/encodings/utf_8.py
# code object from '/Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/encodings/__pycache__/utf_8.cpython-35.pyc'
import 'encodings.utf_8' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x108b07d30>
import '_signal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/encodings/__pycache__/latin_1.cpython-35.pyc matches /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/encodings/latin_1.py
# code object from '/Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/encodings/__pycache__/latin_1.cpython-35.pyc'
import 'encodings.latin_1' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x108af97f0>
# /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/io.cpython-35.pyc matches /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/io.py
# code object from '/Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/io.cpython-35.pyc'
# /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/abc.cpython-35.pyc matches /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/abc.py
# code object from '/Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/abc.cpython-35.pyc'
# /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/_weakrefset.cpython-35.pyc matches /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/_weakrefset.py
# code object from '/Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/_weakrefset.cpython-35.pyc'
import '_weakrefset' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x108b10470>
import 'abc' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x108af9c50>
import 'io' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x108af99e8>
# /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/site.cpython-35.pyc matches /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site.py
# code object from '/Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/site.cpython-35.pyc'
# /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/os.cpython-35.pyc matches /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/os.py
# code object from '/Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/os.cpython-35.pyc'
import 'errno' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/stat.cpython-35.pyc matches /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/stat.py
# code object from '/Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/stat.cpython-35.pyc'
import '_stat' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'stat' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x108b954a8>
# /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/posixpath.cpython-35.pyc matches /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/posixpath.py
# code object from '/Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/posixpath.cpython-35.pyc'
# /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/genericpath.cpython-35.pyc matches /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/genericpath.py
# code object from '/Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/genericpath.cpython-35.pyc'
import 'genericpath' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x108b97d30>
import 'posixpath' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x108b957f0>
# /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/_collections_abc.cpython-35.pyc matches /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/_collections_abc.py
# code object from '/Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/_collections_abc.cpython-35.pyc'
import '_collections_abc' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x108ba03c8>
import 'os' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x108b24278>
# /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/_sitebuiltins.cpython-35.pyc matches /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/_sitebuiltins.py
# code object from '/Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/_sitebuiltins.cpython-35.pyc'
import '_sitebuiltins' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x108b24550>
# /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/sysconfig.cpython-35.pyc matches /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py
# code object from '/Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/sysconfig.cpython-35.pyc'
import 'sysconfig' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x108bd9668>
# /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/_sysconfigdata.cpython-35.pyc matches /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/_sysconfigdata.py
# code object from '/Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/_sysconfigdata.cpython-35.pyc'
import '_sysconfigdata' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x108bdff28>
# /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/_osx_support.cpython-35.pyc matches /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/_osx_support.py
# code object from '/Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/_osx_support.cpython-35.pyc'
# /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/re.cpython-35.pyc matches /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/re.py
# code object from '/Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/re.cpython-35.pyc'
# /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/sre_compile.cpython-35.pyc matches /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/sre_compile.py
# code object from '/Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/sre_compile.cpython-35.pyc'
import '_sre' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/sre_parse.cpython-35.pyc matches /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/sre_parse.py
# code object from '/Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/sre_parse.cpython-35.pyc'
# /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/sre_constants.cpython-35.pyc matches /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/sre_constants.py
# code object from '/Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/sre_constants.cpython-35.pyc'
import 'sre_constants' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x108c0a6a0>
import 'sre_parse' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x108bfed68>
import 'sre_compile' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x108bf5da0>
import '_locale' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/copyreg.cpython-35.pyc matches /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/copyreg.py
# code object from '/Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/copyreg.cpython-35.pyc'
import 'copyreg' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x108c47470>
import 're' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x108bf1eb8>
import '_osx_support' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x108bf1080>
# /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/_bootlocale.cpython-35.pyc matches /Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/_bootlocale.py
# code object from '/Users/fredrik/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/_bootlocale.cpython-35.pyc'
import '_bootlocale' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x108c47390>
import 'site' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x108b17d68>
Python 3.5.2 (default, Aug 30 2016, 00:56:52) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
# /Users/fredrik/code/scikit-learn/__pycache__/sklearn.cpython-35.pyc matches /Users/fredrik/code/scikit-learn/sklearn.py
# code object from '/Users/fredrik/code/scikit-learn/__pycache__/sklearn.cpython-35.pyc'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sklearn.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn import datasets
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/fredrik/code/scikit-learn/sklearn.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn import datasets
ImportError: cannot import name 'datasets'
# clear builtins._
# clear sys.path
# clear sys.argv
# clear sys.ps1
# clear sys.ps2
# clear sys.last_type
# clear sys.last_value
# clear sys.last_traceback
# destroy sklearn
# clear sys.path_hooks
# clear sys.path_importer_cache
# clear sys.meta_path
# clear sys.__interactivehook__
# clear sys.flags
# clear sys.float_info
# restore sys.stdin
# restore sys.stdout
# restore sys.stderr
# cleanup[2] removing encodings.latin_1
# cleanup[2] removing _locale
# cleanup[2] removing __main__
# destroy __main__
# cleanup[2] removing os.path
# cleanup[2] removing _sysconfigdata
# destroy _sysconfigdata
# cleanup[2] removing _bootlocale
# destroy _bootlocale
# cleanup[2] removing sysconfig
# destroy sysconfig
# cleanup[2] removing zipimport
# cleanup[2] removing sre_compile
# cleanup[2] removing _stat
# cleanup[2] removing _collections_abc
# destroy _collections_abc
# cleanup[2] removing posixpath
# cleanup[2] removing _imp
# cleanup[2] removing _weakrefset
# destroy _weakrefset
# cleanup[2] removing marshal
# cleanup[2] removing _frozen_importlib_external
# cleanup[2] removing posix
# cleanup[2] removing sre_constants
# destroy sre_constants
# cleanup[2] removing builtins
# cleanup[2] removing site
# destroy site
# cleanup[2] removing sre_parse
# cleanup[2] removing _weakref
# cleanup[2] removing encodings
# destroy encodings
# cleanup[2] removing errno
# cleanup[2] removing encodings.utf_8
# cleanup[2] removing _codecs
# cleanup[2] removing os
# cleanup[2] removing _frozen_importlib
# cleanup[2] removing _warnings
# cleanup[2] removing sys
# cleanup[2] removing codecs
# cleanup[2] removing abc
# cleanup[2] removing _io
# cleanup[2] removing stat
# cleanup[2] removing encodings.aliases
# cleanup[2] removing copyreg
# cleanup[2] removing io
# destroy io
# destroy abc
# cleanup[2] removing _osx_support
# destroy _osx_support
# cleanup[2] removing _thread
# cleanup[2] removing _sre
# cleanup[2] removing genericpath
# cleanup[2] removing re
# cleanup[2] removing _signal
# cleanup[2] removing _sitebuiltins
# destroy zipimport
# destroy _signal
# destroy _sitebuiltins
# destroy posixpath
# destroy errno
# destroy _stat
# destroy genericpath
# destroy stat
# destroy os
# destroy re
# destroy sre_compile
# destroy copyreg
# destroy sre_parse
# destroy _sre
# destroy _locale
# cleanup[3] wiping encodings.latin_1
# cleanup[3] wiping _imp
# cleanup[3] wiping marshal
# cleanup[3] wiping _frozen_importlib_external
# destroy marshal
# cleanup[3] wiping posix
# destroy posix
# cleanup[3] wiping _weakref
# cleanup[3] wiping encodings.utf_8
# cleanup[3] wiping _codecs
# cleanup[3] wiping _frozen_importlib
# destroy _frozen_importlib_external
# destroy _weakref
# destroy _imp
# cleanup[3] wiping _warnings
# destroy _warnings
# cleanup[3] wiping codecs
# cleanup[3] wiping _io
# destroy io
# cleanup[3] wiping encodings.aliases
# cleanup[3] wiping _thread
# destroy _thread
# cleanup[3] wiping sys
# cleanup[3] wiping builtins
# destroy _frozen_importlib
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is caused from the file that you have named `/Users/fredrik/code/scikit-learn/sklearn.py`

The `sklearn` library is being overridden by your local file, so you just need to rename the `sklearn.py` file in your project to something else and it should work.